# black space and moving view down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a problem. After locking and unlocking the phone when I focused an item on the top, view moves down. When I focused an item on the bottom, view moves to start position. When I move to a new activity and return to the home all is well.

[image]

Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/settings_bg" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_tiles_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</TableLayout>

<include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation" />
```

Comment: android:layout_height="0dp" change this to android:layout_height="match_parent". If you are unable to see the bottom navigation try using frame layout. Or you can use weight to navigation panel also.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the weight when there is only 1 child element ? Try this :

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_tiles_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</TableLayout>
```

If this tablelayout overlaps the navigation at the bottom, do something like :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/settings_bg" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_tiles_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    </TableLayout>

<include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation" />
```

When you use a framelayout, you can make views/layouts overlap.

Comment: This is not just one child element. In the include is another child (LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dp").

Comment: But the included element does not have have a % weight set right so then its best to use a frame and set the height to mp and on the included element, set the minHeight to 60dp and the height to wrap_content. This should work.

Comment: This is happening on all views, not just the present. The problem always after you unlock the screen. After moving to the first focusing-element of the layout.

Comment: The whole layout floats on the screen until you start another activity. In Activity the onTouchEvend is overwrite. This could be the problem? Or maybe the reason is that it dynamically generates a table ? And why always after unlocking ?